# xcode 15 with clang 15 throws error invalid conversion between vector type '__m64'

Tags: xcode, clang

I m getting this error "invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' when I try to build my library for iphone_sim_x64 architecture.
This seems coming from clang 15, which I installed recently along with xcode 15.0.1
Attached complete error I m getting from clang. How can we suppress the error or resolve the error.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"^[[0m^[[91m#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"^[[0m
```

^
In file included from /Users/rsivaraman/eadp-sdk/build/opus/1.00.07/xcframework-IPHONESIM/opus/1.00.07/iphonesim-x64-clang-opt/build/source/BB_runtime.opus_BB_silk_x86.c:2:
In file included from /Users/rsivaraman/packages/opus/1.00.07/installed/silk/x86/NSQ_del_dec_sse4_1.c:32:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:17:
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"^[[0m
^[[91m#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"^[[0m
^
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:54:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:133:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:163:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:193:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:220:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:243:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:264:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:291:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:314:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
^[[91m/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:335:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size^[[0m
return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);